# Почему не инициализируются поля сущности в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

Есть сущность `Book` с методом `isValid`.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String genre;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column
    private int available;

    public static boolean isValidate(@NotNull Book book) {
        return Valids.textIsValid(book.title);
    }
}
```

Её имена совпадают с именами колонок в таблице.
При использовании этого метода контроллером, поля аргумента (объекта `Book`) почему-то пусты, хотя по отладке видно, что внутри присутствует некий `hibernate interceptor`, в поле `target` которого все необходимые данные есть.
[image: Скрин с полученным объектом во время отладки]
[image: Дополнительное поле]
[image: target-поле того же объекта]

С null полями работать соответственно не получается. В чём ошибка и как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А как вы обращаетесь к полям напрямую, если они private?

Comment: Что такое `target`¿

Comment: @NarasuOo Через публичный метод внутри класса.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Во время отладки помимо явно объявленных полей в объекте появляется `$$_hibernate_interceptor`, внутри которого и находится `target`

Comment: Я, конечно, может чего-то не понимаю, но конструктор по умолчанию всегда должен быть описан в любых сущностях.

Comment: @Митяй Аннотация `@NoArgsConstructor` заменяет явно определенный конструктор. После ручной замены на пустой конструктор проблема остаётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас возникла аналогичная проблема, если у вас используется ModelMapper, то возможно это может помочь: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/442

В нашем случае просто помог апгрейд на версию 2.3.3

Также возможно ваша проблема решается просто получением через getter'ы, нежели прямое обращение к полям

Comment: Вы правы, помогло обращение к полям через геттеры. Всё дело в том, что использовалась "ленивая инициализация", и, судя по всему, чтобы программа поняла, что нужно "заполнить" поле, нужно было обратиться к нему именно через геттер.